# How can I return null if columns have not values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web-services

How can I **return null if columns have not values** and **return blank (only " ")without any character for some specific fields** according to this example.

```
       [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public DataTable GetEmployeeInformation(string USERID)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCon"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM VW_NTB_EIM_O365 WHERE USERID=@USERID"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERID", USERID);
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            dt.TableName = "NTB_EIM_O365";
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            if (dt == null)
                            {
                                return null;
                            }

                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you're disposing the datatable on returning.

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())   // <---- using calls the Dispose()
{
    dt.TableName = "NTB_EIM_O365";
    sda.Fill(dt);
    if (dt == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return dt;
}
```

---

Don't use using, because the instance shouldn't be disposed when returned. You question is kinda vague, but if I understand it correctly, this is what you're looking for. At least, it would help you on your way.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "NTB_EIM_O365";
sda.Fill(dt);

if(dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    return null;

// check the first row:
bool allEmpty = true;

for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dt.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0][columnIndex].ToString()))
    {
        allEmpty = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(allEmpty)
    return null;

return dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Null values will directly come from the DB(if they are present in DB for that specific row/column), anyhow if you want to check null/any other condition for a cell in data table, here is the code

```
if(dt != null && dt.Rows.count > 0){
      foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dr.Field<string>("col")))
                    {
                        //do something
                        dr["somecol"] = null;
                    }
                    if (dr.Field<string>("somecol") == "someValue")
                    {
                        dr["somecol"] = string.Empty;
                        //do something
                    }
                }
}
else 
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
public bool EmptyDataTable(DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count < 1)
    return true;

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dt.Rows[i].Field<string>("columnName")))
         {
             return false;
         }
     }

     return true;
}
```

And then:

```
if (EmptyDataTable(dt))
{
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count>0)
         return dt;
      else
         return null;
```

OR

```
  if(dt !=null)
    {
      if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
      {
          return dt;
      }
   }
     return null;
```